# Where do I place the .java file in alfresco following jeff pots' behavior article?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

In [his tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-behavior/behavior-article.pdf) Jeff Pots gives java code at page 10/11, the bean refers to the class of this java code as such

```
class="com.someco.behavior.Rating"
```

but where do I place the .java file itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I'd learn a bit about Java, I mean just doing stuff from a book/article and not understanding what you're doing is stupid.

When you're doing writing your first Hello World Java app.

Then do the following:

1. You'd probably have a Java IDE to develop in, load the java class (copy/paste/create new class) in a new Java Project
2. Build your Java Project and you'll get .class files in your default /bin folder
3. Copy the .class files with their structure from /bin to your Alfresco project and put it in WEB-INF/classes
4. OR create from your Java Project a .jar file (do some research here), then place the .jar file in WEB-INF/lib/

If you don't get this, the you'd probably haven't done your research properly.

Comment: I thought WEB-INF is a bad place to put stuff because Tomcat will delete that file at unpredicatable times?

Comment: I believe what I need is  "web application classpath" is WEB-INF it?

Comment: also do you mean alfresco-4.2.c/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes ? so I add folders there? as I understand it's alfresco-4.2.c/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/com/someco then?

Comment: The .java need to be compiled (into .classes) and then you place the compiled class files into where Tahir mentioned or you can package them and drop them into the folder specified in the answer.

Comment: Yes, and now why will tomcat delete your class files? There are times when your run an AMP file that it will remove the alfresco directory and will use your war. If you want to do it properly than inject the .jar file like I said in the .war file so it's always there.